# How to create customer custom Drop Down attributes in magento 2

Tags: customer-attribute, dropdown-attribute

> Namespace/Module/setup/installData.php

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY,'credit_type',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Credit Type requested',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                    'required' => false,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'sort_order' => 167,
                    'system' => false,
                    'position' => 167,
                    'adminhtml_only' => 1,
                    'option' =>
                        array (
                            'values' =>
                                array (
                                    271 => 'Credit Card',
                                    272 => 'Paypal',
                                    273 => 'Master Card',
                                    274 => 'Visa',
                                ),
                        ),
                ]
            );
            $myAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'credit_type');
            // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
            $myAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create','wholesale_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
            $myAttribute->save();
```

> My template.phtml file code:

```
       <div class="control">
            <select name="mySelect" id="myselect" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Requested Credit Type')) ?>" class="validate-select">
                <option disabled selected value> -- Please Select Credit Type Requested -- </option>
                <option value="271">Credit Card</option>
                <option value="272">Open Terms</option>
                <option value="273">Mega / NBA</option>
                <option value="274">Cantrex</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Data doesn't store in backend

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Magento 2? But I see the path from Magento 1

> Namespace/Module/sql/module_steup/installData.php

It’s not quite clear what you want, but I see that you’ve left out the attribute set and the customer group.

```
$myAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'credit_type');
$myAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create','wholesale_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
$attribute->addData([
                      'attribute_set_id' => 1,
                      'attribute_group_id' => 1
                    ]);
$myAttribute->save();
```

Remove the module from the `setup_module` table and install again.

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

-> Add bellow installation script in your module at path app/code/{Namespace}

```
/{Module-Name}/Setup/InstallData.php


<?php
/**
 * @author      AR
 * @category    AR
 * @package     AR_CustomerAttribute
 */
namespace {Namespace}\{Module-name}\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type', [

            'type'          => 'static',
            'label'         => 'Customer Type',
            'input'         => 'select',
            'source'        => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'required'      => false,
            'sort_order'    => 210,
            'visible'       => false,
            'system'        => false,
            'validate_rules'=> 'a:0:{}',
            'position'      => 210,
            'admin_checkout' => 1,
            'option'         => ['values' => ['Buyer', 'Seller']],
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

-> it's working for me please use above code.

Comment: I have four values: ['values' => ['Buyer', 'Seller','creditcard','paypal']],

Comment: Yes you can add  ['values' => ['Buyer', 'Seller','creditcard','paypal']], it's working.

Comment: In .phtml file, how can I use that values:       <div class="control">
            <select name="mySelect" id="myselect" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Requested Credit Type')) ?>" class="validate-select">
                <option disabled selected value> -- Please Select Credit Type Requested -- </option>
                <option value="271">Credit Card</option>
                <option value="272">Open Terms</option>
                <option value="273">Mega / NBA</option>
                <option value="274">Cantrex</option>
            </select>
        </div>